# How to have a process name different from package name for Android app?

Tags: android, process

I have an android app with some package name. (like com.example.name)
But I would like to run the app in a process under some other name (like com.example.othername). BTW, I do not have another app with package name com.example.othername.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use the [`android:process`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#proc) attribute on the `<application>` tag in your manifest file.